# uwp: how to bind data inside DataTemplate outside of x:DataType?

Tags: c#, uwp, combobox, bind

i have MyPage.xaml and MyPage.xaml.cs files.
Into .xaml file i written a data template like this:

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate" x:DataType="local:MyClass">
            ...
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            ...
        </DataTemplate>
```

I can bind name attribute of MyClass correctly.
Now i need to bind an attribute of .xaml.cs file but DataTemplate show me only MyClass data. How can i bind data from .xaml.cs page? Outside DataTemplate (but in the same xaml file) i can see any attribute of .xaml.cs file.
I need to bind a List of objects to a combobox like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{x:Bind myList}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></ComboBox>
```

but myList is an .xaml.cs attribute.
I want to view a string name attribute of objects of the list.

Thank you for your help

Comment: I usually use WPF so I don't know if it works but you can try adding a name to the page like: `<Page x:Name="page" ... >` and in the ComboBox: `ItemsSource="{x:Bind myList ElementName=page}"`.

Answer (score 2):

> uwp: how to bind data inside DataTemplate outside of x:DataType?

For your recrement, we suggest you use `Binding` to replace `x:Bind`, You could use `Binding` to access current root DataContext with `ElementName`.

For example

```
<Grid x:Name="GridRoot">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=GridRoot, Path=DataContext.Options}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

**Code Behind**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
    public List<string> Options { get; set; } = new List<string>() {"One","Two","Three" };
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; } = new List<Item>() 
    { 
        new Item { Name = "HH" },
        new Item { Name = "ZZ" }, 
        new Item { Name = "MM" }
    };
}
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @ Nico Zhu I have not tested it, but according to the following Issue, your proposed solution will not work. https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/2508

Answer (score 0):

If you have several nested controls (for ex., several nested grids), you should test for several levels of the "RootGrid". One of them can work.
This is the UWP - sometimes it is not possible to guess what is working as described.

**Example**:
You have the UserControl (with x:Name="Ctl1") with several nested Grid or some other containers. And, at the end (the deeper level), you have a ListView with an ItemTemplate.
If you want to bind to the property of the DataContext on the root UserControl, the construction

```
{Binding ElementName=Ctl1, Path=DataContext.Prop1}
```

works not always.
Sometimes, you should try such construction for every nested Grids (use them as ElementName) until it will work.
And, sometimes, such construction will not work at all and you have to use the 'code behind'.
This is especially true for the DataGrid control.

The binding engine of the UWP is very capricious.

Comment: This answer is a bit vague. Maybe you can give it a little bit more depth. Consider checking the guide on [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).